# Updating values of a column from multiple columns if the values are present in those columns

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe

I am trying to update Col1 with values from Col2,Col3... if values are found in any of them. A row would have only one value, but it can have "-" but that should be treated as NaN

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ['A',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
        [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'C',np.nan,np.nan], 
        [np.nan,np.nan,"-",np.nan,'B',np.nan],
        [np.nan,np.nan,"-",np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]
    ],
    columns = ['Col1','Col2','Col3','Col4','Col5','Col6']
)

print(df)

   Col1 Col2 Col3   Col4    Col5     Col6
0    A  NaN  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
1  NaN  NaN  NaN       C     NaN     NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN     NaN       B     NaN 
3  NaN  NaN  NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

I want the output to be:

```
   Col1 
0    A  
1    C  
2    B  
3  NaN
```

I tried to use the update function:

```
for col in df.columns[1:]:
    df[Col1].update(col)
```

It works on this small `DataFrame` but when I run it on a larger `DataFrame` with a lot more `rows` and `columns`, I am losing a lot of values in between. Is there any better function to do this preferably without a loop. Please help I tried with many other methods, including using `.loc` but no joy.

Comment: Does each row have only one value?

Comment: each row usually has only one value, but each column can have more than one value

Comment: How should the value in `Col1` look like if there are multiple values found in that row?

Comment: @Rabinzel,Yes each row has only one value but each column can have multiple values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to go about it

```
# convert the values in the row to series, and sort, NaN moves to the end
df2=df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x).sort_values(ignore_index=True), axis=1)

# rename df2 column as df columns
df2.columns=df.columns

# drop where all values in the column as null
df2.dropna(axis=1, how='all', inplace=True) 

print(df2)
```

```
Col1
0   A
1   C
2   B
3   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```py
from functools import reduce

reduce(
    lambda x, y: x.combine_first(df[y]),
    df.columns[1:],
    df[df.columns[0]]
).to_frame()
```

The following `DataFrame` is the result of the previous code:

```bash
  Col1
0    A
1    C
2    B
3  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Python has a one-liner generator for this type of use case:

```py
# next((x for x in list if condition), None)

df["Col1"] = df.apply(lambda row: next((x for x in row if not pd.isnull(x) and x != "-"), None), axis=1)

[Out]:
0       A
1       C
2       B
3    None
```